# Powershell Exclusion of Folders with matching filenames

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm using something like the below script to exclude Folders.
The problem is that there is a file name as of a folder name and i only want to exclude the folder and not the file. For example in the below i want to exclude "B" Folder only and not "B.txt" file whereas the current code as shown below excludes both file and folder.

```
$exclude = @("*.cer")
$excludeMatch = @("Member", "A", "B" , "C" , "D")
[regex] $excludeMatchRegEx = ‘(?i)‘ + (($excludeMatch |foreach {[regex]::escape($_)}) –join “|”) + ‘’
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse -Exclude $exclude | 
where { $excludeMatch -eq $null -or `enter code here`$_.FullName.Replace($Source, "") -notmatch $excludeMatchRegEx} |
 Copy-Item -Destination {
 if ($_.PSIsContainer) {
   Join-Path $Dest `enter code here`$_.Parent.FullName.Substring($source.length)
  } else {
   Join-Path $Dest $_.FullName.Substring($source.length)
 }
 } -Force -Exclude $exclude
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is exclude folders, it's pretty easy to do:

`Get-ChildItem -Path \Temp -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false}`

If you want to compound this using a regex, you could also add that to your Where-Object statement:

`Get-ChildItem -Path \Temp -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false -and $_.Name -match $regexPattern }`

You also throw a -notmatch in there if you feel you DON'T want certain things.

One thing to keep in mind with PowerShell... In my experience, the pipeline is GREAT for executing commands from the shell, but that's generally when you're doing things that are very well-defined in your personal command dictionary (things like `Get-ADUser -Filter {GivenName -eq "Sam"}`, but it isn't as good when you're trying to do script-y sort of things -- in that case, you're really best doing filtering with Where-Object, and selecting down to the items that you need. PowerShell has a pretty reasonably featured debugger for if you want a good debugging experience, and you can't really step into the pipeline as it stands today to evaluate how something works. Especially if you're having problems with a script or a series of commands, the debugger can be your absolute best friend, and I'd highly recommend breaking things out into individual statements to do some analyses there.

Also, the Get-Member cmdlet is quite arguably one of the top-ten most useful cmdlets in Windows PowerShell (along with Get-Help, Where-Object, Select-Object, Get-Command, and a few others). It really helps when you're starting to evaluate how a script is going to function to analyze the properties of the objects you're working with (in your case, System.IO.FileInfo and System.IO.DirectoryInfo), to help reduce the amount of scratching your head later.

I hope this helps!

**Edit:**

After reading the comments, I am amending my answer to better fit the problem description.

If you do not wish to preserve the source-folder hierarchy, then you can just run `Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false -and $_.Name -match $regexPattern } | Copy-Item -Destination **target_folder**`. Copy-Item should simply treat the output as all belonging to one location. Note that you can also run Copy-Item (and most other cmdlets that modify something support the `-WhatIf` parameter. You'll want to verify the output before running it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,

Comment: The Issue is that i have folder within folder like the below structure C:\Customers\Customer1\Config\x1, X2 now i want to copy some files in the folder "Config" and exclude the folders "X1" and "X2". The next level will be C:\Customers\Customer2\Config\x1,x2 so i would want to exclude "X1" , "X2" again and copy the fies. The bottom line is that there is a few config files which are repeated under each customers folder and i want to copy those files only. There is a few folders also matching the name of one of the files which i want to exclude(Folders only) and not the files.

Comment: If I understand you, you only want the files from the top-level dir? Or the to plus subfolders, but not two of the folders?

Comment: Yes you are right .. there is only one level of folders that i need files from, but I have multiple folders with the same structure so the files will be copied from each folder like below C:\Folder 1\MyFolder, C:\Folder 2\MyFolder, C:\Folder 3\MyFolder. i need specific files from MyFolder from all three folders on C:\

Comment: Please make not of the updated answer. If you have any questions, please reply.